# Является ли фразеологизм словосочетанием по традиционной точке зрения (Скобликова, Белошапкова) и по номинативной теории (Виноградова)?

Tags: синтаксис, фразеология, словосочетания

Она пошла прочь, **несолоно хлебавши**.
Является ли это фразеологическое сочетание частью словосочетания `пошла **несолоно хлебавши**`, где фразеологизм будет являться обстоятельством, привязанным слабым глагольным управлением. Можно ли характеризовать фразеологизм как синтаксему?

Comment: Правильно будет: с точки зрения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под ФЕ понимаются фразеологические единства, а не фразеологические единицы (последние могут быть разных типов и с разной степенью нечленимости), то с позиций АГ-80 — да, не относятся. Впрочем, исключение фразеологизмов из состава словосочетаний сегодня считается практически общепризнанной точкой зрения.

[Современный русский](https://ask.fm/russian/answers/162220072508)

Что касается синтаксемы.

Вопрос довольно дискуссионный. Если следовать определению, согласно которому синтаксема есть «минимальная номинативная синтаксическая единица, дающая наименование отдельным элементам ситуации и выступающая как носитель элементарного смысла. Синтаксема выступает в качестве элементарного конструктивного компонента в составе словосочетания или простого предложения. По своей структуре синтаксема представляет собой морфологическую форму любой части речи, которая рассматривается не как компонент морфологической парадигмы, а как элемент синтаксических построений», ответ должен быть скорее отрицательный. Но как тогда квалифицировать зависимый компонент в словосочетании «работать спустя рукава»?..

[Современный русский](https://ask.fm/russian/answers/162220082236)

Comment: Люблю Ваши ответы, Серж! Но, простите... 1. Две ссылки совершенно одинаковы (и совершенно не читаются). 2. **ФЕ** — это единства или единицы?

Comment: Римма Михайловна, странно. У меня открываются. Да, ссылки одинаковы. Но они к разным ответам. Не знаю, что даже можно сделать. ФЕ( фразеологические единстнва).