# О фразеологизме "несолоно хлебавши"

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

**По какому правилу** обособляется или не обособляется фразеологизм в приведенных предложениях (примеры из Накорпуса)? **Каким членом предложения** он является (если обстоятельством, то каким именно)?

*Так и вернулся домой **несолоно хлебавши**, ухлопав полдня неизвестно на что. Но американец уступил и покинул город на Неве **несолоно хлебавши**.*

*Она пошла прочь, **несолоно хлебавши**. Налетчики попросту убрались восвояси, **несолоно хлебавши**. Но сделка не состоялась, и он покинул посольство, несолоно хлебавши.*

Спасибо.

Comment: (1) Какой здесь образ действия?  Можно сказать:  вернулся  (каким?) неудовлетворенным, не получившим желаемое, с пустыми руками.(2)  Все предложения из художественной литературы, почему одни обособлены, а другие нет? Вы же не объясняете разницу вариантов. Надо работать  с конкретными предложениями, каждое решение индивидуально.   А Грамоте.ру надо почаще читать предисловие у Розенталя, где он пишет о вариативности русской пунктуации, тогда она будет немного грамотнее. Да, и спасибо за комментарии.

Comment: Sharon, a по-моему, все явно: в необособленных вариантах фразеологизм является частью СИС.Вы и сами об этом пишете. А вот обособленный вариант  - это присоединительный член предложения.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за комментарий. Мой вопрос  соотносится с другим вопросом, на который не стали отвечать (как вы думаете, почему) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461869/Является-ли-фразеологизм-словосочетанием-по-традиционной-точке-зрения-Скобликов. Там надо было определить оборот как синтаксему по синтаксической роли. И вот как ее определить? Если это необособленный вариант и оборот входит в состав сказуемого, то как определительный или обстоятельственный?

Comment: А если мы его обособляем, то это обособленное определение или что?  Ну и само обособление или необсобление в сходных конструкциях как объяснить?

Comment: Во втором случае мне тоже представляется СИС.

Comment: Т.е. определительный оборот в обоих случаях.

Comment: Вероятно, да, вы правы.  Тогда это обособленное определение? Кроме того,  меня  смущает заданный вопрос о синтаксеме. При обособлении присловного управления нет, связь становится полупредикативной, а там говорится о словосочетании со слабым глагольным управлением. Вот меня и интригует этот вопрос, может быть, в нем какая-то некорректность. А вы не могли бы ответить на него или не знаете кого-нибудь, кто мог бы ответить?

Comment: @ Sharon. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461869/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2